# How to convert "MMM DD,YYYY" to proper date format?

Tags: r, lubridate

I have a column full of dates in format `"mmm dd,yyyy"`.

They look like these:
`"Dec 21, 2015"`
`"Aug 23, 2018"` etc.

I tried to convert those dates to a proper date format for further data processing by doing `as.Date("Dec 21, 2015")` or `as.Date(as.character("Dec 21, 2015"))`but neither worked.

Here is the error message:
`Error in charToDate(x) : character string is not in a standard unambiguous format`

I am wondering what is a good way to properly convert such nonstandard data format into proper data format and class "YYYY-MM-DD" (e.g. "2015-12-21")? Should I use regex syntax to solve that?

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: `as.Date(c('Dec 21, 2015', 'Aug 23, 2018'), '%b %d, %Y')`

Answer (score 4):

Using lubridate:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df <- data.frame(date = c('Dec 21, 2015','Aug 23, 2018'))
df
          date
1 Dec 21, 2015
2 Aug 23, 2018
df %>% mutate(date1 = mdy(df$date))
          date      date1
1 Dec 21, 2015 2015-12-21
2 Aug 23, 2018 2018-08-23
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `base`:

```r
x <- "Dec 21, 2015"

as.Date(x, "%b %d, %y")
#> [1] "2020-12-21"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Depending on what your date variable is named, it can look something like this:

```
df$date <- as.Date(df$date, "%b %d, %y")
```

Answer (score 2):

An option with `anydate` from `anytime`

```
library(anytime)
df$date <- anydate(df$date)
df$date
#[1] "2015-12-21" "2018-08-23"
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(date = c('Dec 21, 2015','Aug 23, 2018'))
```